# Where to add additional js and css file to be used by view.phtml in Magento

Tags: javascript, css, magento

I want to add an additional .css file (my.css) and .js file (my.js) to be included in the head of view.phtml. I understand that I need to modify my theme's local.xml and add the following in the Product View section within :

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/my.js</name></action>
   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/my.css</name><params/>  
       </action>
</reference>
```

My .js a function selects a specific .css depending on the user input (not sure is the href path should be like this):

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite/skin/frontend/[mytheme]/css/my.css"     
 media="print" />
```

I put my.js directly in the js folder in my Magento installation root and my.css in the skin/frontend/[my-theme]/css.
Unfortunately, this does not work. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could see in your browser's inspector tool what files are failed to load, then decide what is wrong and correct. What I could say from your post is that file included by `skin_js` supposed to be under skin folder of current theme. If you want to include script from root js folder you better use

```
<action method="addJs"><script>some_folder_under_root_js/some_script.js</script></action>
```